# Removing duplicates from a cell in excel

Tags: string, vba, excel, duplicates

So I've got a list of strings, for which some of the strings contain duplicates.

For example:

> 13-Hexadecenoic acid;13-methyl-4-pentadecenoic
>   acid;14-Methyl-6-pentadecenoic acid;15-Hexadecanolide;3-Hexadecenoic
>   acid;4-hexadecenoic acid;13-Hexadecenoic
>   acid;13-methyl-4-pentadecenoic acid;14-Methyl-6-pentadecenoic
>   acid;15-Hexadecanolide;3-Hexadecenoic acid;4-hexadecenoic acid;

So I came across a macro online and tweaked it to work for my problem, which goes like this:

```
Function stringOfUniques(inputString As String) As String
    Dim inArray() As String
    Dim xVal As Variant
    inArray = Split(inputString, ";")
    For Each xVal In inArray
        If InStr(stringOfUniques, Trim(xVal)) = 0 Then _
        stringOfUniques = stringOfUniques & Trim(xVal) & ","
    Next xVal

End Function
```

And for some of my strings this works brilliantly, however for the example above it will return the string with the duplicates removed, but weirdly will get rid off both copies of one of the words '3-Hexadecenoic acid'. So basically

What I should get:

> 13-Hexadecenoic acid;13-methyl-4-pentadecenoic
>   acid;14-Methyl-6-pentadecenoic acid;15-Hexadecanolide;3-Hexadecenoic
>   acid;4-hexadecenoic acid;

What I actually get:

> 13-Hexadecenoic acid;13-methyl-4-pentadecenoic
>   acid;14-Methyl-6-pentadecenoic acid;15-Hexadecanolide;4-hexadecenoic
>   acid;

Is there something in my code that's causing this to happen?

Comment: Apologies for the example, probably not the easiest on the eyes

Comment: I am guessing it has something to do with `InStr` -> _Returns an integer specifying the start position of the first occurrence of one **string within another**._ So it probably is going to treat `13-Hexadecenoic acid` as a duplicate of `3-Hexadecenoic acid` Thus even after removing the first `3-Hexadecenoic acid` it will still find `13-Hexadecenoic acid` and remove the second

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably there are several ways to do this, but `Dictionary` objects are great for enforcing uniqueness.

```
Function stringOfUniques(inputString As String, delimiter as String)
Dim xVal As Variant
Dim dict as Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each xVal In Split(inputString, delimiter)
    dict(xVal) = xVal
Next xVal

stringOfUniques = Join(dict.Keys(),",")
End Function
```

This function has also been modified to accept a variable delimiter argument, so you will pass the input string *and* the delimiter: `";"` to the function, which will return a comma-separated string.

**A Note on Dictionaries:**

Dictionaries store key/value pairs. The *keys* must be unique.

In the example, I use a simple assignment to the dictionary object:  `dict(key) = key`.  A dictionary will automatically *add or overwrite* an item when referenced by it's key, so this is a really simple way of enforcing uniqueness.

In other circumstances (i.e., you want to *count* the number of occurrences of each key), you would want to test using the `dict.Exists(key)` in order to modify the `value` without overwriting the key/value pair, for example:

```
'Assigns a "count" value to the dictionary for each unique Key
For Each xVal In Split(inputString, delimiter)
    If dict.Exists(xVal) Then
        dict(xVal) = dict(xVal) + 1
    Else
        dict(xVal) = 1
    End If
Next xVal

'Read the "count" from each key:
For Each xVal in dict.Keys()
    MsgBox xVal & " appears " & dict(xVal) & " times"
Next
```